# Ethernet cannot work after resuming from suspending (S2RAM)

Tags: ethernet, suspend

I am working on EthernetAVB module. My board can be suspended by the command

```
echo mem > /sys/power/state
```

But when resuming from suspending, the eth0 doesn't work. The phenomenon are:

- Able ping loopback: $ ping 127.0.0.1 --> Ok
- Power of PHY is off (power down)
- Unable ping to neighbors: $ ping 192.168.1.1 --> Failed

I assumed that the network layer (comply with OSI model) is ok, because I can ping loopback. I thought the problem happened in physical layers, related to:

- PHY ic (my board using Micrel Phys ksz9031)
- MDIO bus
- And the last is phy_dev
- Maybe the issue able to happen on Ethernet Controller (my case is Ethernet AVB)

I tried to disable "suspend" the PHY ic (power of ksz9031) - keep the PHY waken. After resuming, the power indicating led is ON, but still cannot ping the other neighbors.
By the way, I saw that my system (ethernet) cannot jump to RUNNING state after resuming.
[image]

The above is the way PM platform work.

And Block Diagram of EthernetAVB in my board.
[image]

I drew a part of PHY state machine for purpose of detecting the issue (not completely)
[image]

More details:

**PHY state machine states**:

```
DOWN: PHY device and driver are not ready for anything.  probe() should be called if and only if the PHY is in this state, given that the PHY device exists.
 - PHY driver probe function will, depending on the PHY, set the state to STARTING or READY

STARTING:  PHY device is coming up, and the ethernet driver is not ready.  PHY drivers may set this in the probe function.  If they do, they are responsible for making sure the state is eventually set to indicate whether the PHY is UP or READY, depending on the state when the PHY is done starting up.
 - PHY driver will set the state to READY
 - start will set the state to PENDING

READY: PHY is ready to send and receive packets, but the controller is not.  By default, PHYs which do not implement probe will be set to this state by phy_probe().  If the PHY driver knows the PHY is ready, and the PHY state is STARTING, then it sets this STATE.
     - start will set the state to UP
PENDING: PHY device is coming up, but the ethernet driver is ready.  phy_start will set this state if the PHY state is STARTING.
 - PHY driver will set the state to UP when the PHY is ready

UP: The PHY and attached device are ready to do work. Interrupts should be started here.
 - timer moves to AN

AN: The PHY is currently negotiating the link state.  Link is therefore down for now.  phy_timer will set this state when it detects the state is UP.  config_aneg will set this state whenever called with phydev->autoneg set to AUTONEG_ENABLE.
- If autonegotiation finishes, but there's no link, it sets the state to NOLINK.
- If aneg finishes with link, it sets the state to RUNNING, and calls adjust_link
- If autonegotiation did not finish after an arbitrary amount of time, autonegotiation should be tried again if the PHY supports "magic" autonegotiation (back to AN)
- If it didn't finish, and no magic_aneg, move to FORCING.

NOLINK: PHY is up, but not currently plugged in.
- If the timer notes that the link comes back, we move to RUNNING
- config_aneg moves to AN
- phy_stop moves to HALTED

FORCING: PHY is being configured with forced settings
- if link is up, move to RUNNING
- If link is down, we drop to the next highest setting, and retry (FORCING) after a timeout
- phy_stop moves to HALTED

RUNNING: PHY is currently up, running, and possibly sending and/or receiving packets
- timer will set CHANGELINK if we're polling (this ensures the link state is polled every other cycle of this state machine, which makes it every other second)
- irq will set CHANGELINK
- config_aneg will set AN
- phy_stop moves to HALTED

CHANGELINK: PHY experienced a change in link state
- timer moves to RUNNING if link
- timer moves to NOLINK if the link is down
- phy_stop moves to HALTED

HALTED: PHY is up, but no polling or interrupts are done. Or PHY is in an error state.
- phy_start moves to RESUMING

RESUMING: PHY was halted, but now wants to run again.
- If we are forcing, or aneg is done, timer moves to RUNNING
- If aneg is not done, timer moves to AN
- phy_stop moves to HALTED
```

I raise some assumptions/hypothesis:

- After suspended, the system goes to HALTED state, but cannot change to RUNNING state.
- Because of a certain reason, the system goes to DOWN state, and cannot move to READY state and UP again.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Keep below things at least during resuming from suspended state to resolve the issue.

o   Enable AVB-DMAC Mode Register working with high-speed peripheral bus clock (the AVB-DMAC module currently uses gPTP clock to read/write data from Queues (Best effort and Network control).

o   Restore descriptor base address table (DBAT register) in the URAM.

o   Enable interrupts for Best Effort Queue và Network Control Queue

o   Re-init DMAC và E-MAC devices

o   Initialize PTP Clock driver to provide clock for DMAC

o   Enable transmits for all queues to allow the upper layer to transmit frames but it does not restart transmission.

o   Re-start PHY device

o   Mark device as attached from system and restart if needed.